# Data statement for Matrices

Tags: arrays, fortran, matrix-multiplication

I want to use the data statement to initialize matrices in Fortran. In my opinion, one advantage of using this method is that it provides a compact way of initializing matrices. However, the way I used it in the example below resulted in an error in the calculation. Both Z1 and ZZ1 should give a matrix of size 2x1 equal to [7;13] (ZZ1 = [7;13], Z1 = [10;12]). I believe that an option such as order=(/2,1/) should be used, but I have not been able to find it. Can someone help?

```
program test_Multiplication
  implicit none
  integer :: Xp1(3,1), b1(2,1), IW1_1(2,3), Z1(2,1)
  integer :: XXp1(3,1), bb1(2,1), IIW1_1(2,3), ZZ1(2,1)
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  ! with data statement !
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  data Xp1(1:3,1) &
  /1, &
   2, &
   3/
  data IW1_1(1:2,1:3) &
  /1, 1, 1, &
   2, 2, 2/
  data b1(1:2,1) &
  /1, &
   1/
  
  Z1 = matmul(IW1_1,Xp1)+b1
  print*, 'Z1', Z1

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  ! without data statement !
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  XXp1 = reshape( (/1, &
   2, &
   3 /), &
   shape(XXp1), order=(/2,1/) )
  
  IIW1_1 = reshape( (/ 1, 1, 1, &
   2, 2, 2/), &
   shape(IIW1_1), order=(/2,1/) )
  
  bb1 = reshape( (/1, &
   1/), &
   shape(bb1), order=(/2,1/) )

  ZZ1 = matmul(IIW1_1,XXp1)+bb1
  print*, 'ZZ1', ZZ1

end program test_Multiplication
```

Comment: You should add a tag indicating the programming language. Fortran?

Comment: Yes, Fortran. Added.

Comment: Fortran is a column major language.  PS:  I almost skipped answering your question due to excessive use of line continuation.  This makes it difficult to parse the code.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Please show us what the program prints and what you want it to print instead. In my opinion, the data statement shoukd be kept to rest in history, though.

Comment: Why do you want a data statement? That is so 1970s. Just use an initialization if you want to do this sort of thing, provided you understand the consequences of the implicit `Save` (which applies to both methods)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@user790082,

Steve has already given your answer as a comment (Fortran uses column-major order: first index changes fastest in memory). If you *must* use a data statement then change your initialisation of IW1_1 to

```
  data IW1_1(1:2,1:3) /1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2 /
```

(Line continuations are a considerable distraction in this instance.)